# OnAppearing not triggering when user switch between Apps/ Device Locked/Unlocked

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a issue on triggering OnAppearing on the dismiss of PopModalAsync that is not executing when the user moves the app to background and re-opens again.

Scenario is as below:

1. Open Page -> (Page1)
2. Page1 OnDisappearing will trigger, since I am Pushing the Modal
3. PushModalAsync -> Some Modal page(ModalPage1)
4. Turn off screen, or move the app to background.
5. Turn on screen or open the App from recents
6. OnAppearing of Page1 will trigger immediately not ModalPage1's OnAppearing
7. On dismiss of ModalPage1, no event will trigger in Page1.

According to Page life cycle, on dismiss of Modal, respective page OnAppearing event should trigger. In this scenario it is not happening!

Any workaround for this scenario?

Comment: Check OnSleep and OnResume in App.xaml.cs

Comment: facing this on iOS or android?

Comment: I am facing this in Android

Answer (score 0):

> OnAppearing not triggering when user switch between Apps/ Device Locked/Unlocked

In android device, when user switch between Apps/ Device Locked/Unlocked the `OnAppearing()` and `OnDisappearing()` will not be invoked. However, it will invoke `OnResume()/OnSleep()` in **App.xaml.cs**. You could refer to Lifecycle methods in Xamarin Forms [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/app-lifecycle#lifecycle-methods)

```
protected override void OnSleep()
{
    Debug.WriteLine ("OnSleep");
}
protected override void OnResume()
{
    Debug.WriteLine ("OnResume");
}
```

If you need to know which page appears between Apps/ Device Locked/Unlocked, you could use  [Xamarin.Essentials: Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android) to set ***a custom page flag*** when `OnAppearing()` be invoked. And later back to App, get the ***custom page flag*** from `OnResume()` method.

For example, save ***custom page flag***  when `OnAppearing()`：

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    Preferences.Set("CurrentPage", typeof(CurrentPage).ToString());
}
```

And get data to know which page is showing when `OnResume()`:

```
protected override void OnResume()
{
    Console.WriteLine("OnResume");
    var pageValue = Preferences.Get("CurrentPage", typeof(MainPage).ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Current page is "+ pageValue);
}
```